Generalization of mean value theorem?
For differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the mean value theorem states:
given $a, b$ there exists $c$ such that
$$
f(b) - f(a) = f'(c) (b-a).  
$$
Is there something similar for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$?
What I am looking for is: given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $c$ such that
$$
f(b) - f(a) = Jac_f(c) (b - a). 
$$
Here $Jac_f$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$.
I know this is true for $k=1$.
Does it also hold true when $k > 1$? Thank you!

You might be looking for something like the final proposition in the section on Vector Valued Functions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions

The one in Wikipedia involves inequality and not of the above form. so it's a bit different from what I'm looking for. thank you

I think you might not have scrolled down to the correct proposition (it's labelled a Proposition rather than Theorem or Inequality). What I'm looking at appears directly before the section on "Cases where the theorem cannot be applied", and does not have an inequality.

False for $n=k=2$. $e^{2\pi i}-e^{0}\neq e^{z}(2\pi-0)$ for any $z$. Translate this from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R^{2}$.

@Kyle my apologies! Something like this was what I was hoping for. Thank you!!

Great! Glad it helped :)
